# Why doesnt my delegate function didReceiveData get called in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, game-center

Im making a multiplayer real time Game Center game and I am using this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2. I got all the way to the part in the console where it says "Match has started successfully." The next delegate function that is supposed to be called is the didReceiveData function but it never gets called. I did it exactly as it says in the tutorial but it doesn't work for me.

```
    //MultiplayerNetworking.swift
  func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotePlayer playerID: GKPlayer!) {



    let message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory

    if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {
        let messageRandomNumber = UnsafePointer<MessageRandomNumber>(data.bytes).memory

        println("Received random number: \(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)")

        var tie = false

        if(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber == _ourRandomNumber) {
            println("Tie")
            tie = true
            _ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
            self.sendRandomNumber()
        }
        else {
            var dictionary = ["\(playerIDKey)":"\(playerID)", "\(randomNumberKey)":"\(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)"]
            self.processReceivedRandomNumber(dictionary)
        }

        if(_receivedAllRandomNumbers) {
            _isPlayer1 = self.isLocalPlayerPlayer1()
        }

        if(!tie && _receivedAllRandomNumbers) {
            if(_gameState == GameState.kGameStateWaitingForRandomNumber) {
                _gameState = GameState.kGameStateWaitingForStart
            }
            self.tryStartGame()
        }
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameBegin) {
        println("Begin game message received")
        _gameState = GameState.kGameStateActive
        self.delegate?.setCurrentPlayerIndex(self.indexForLocalPlayer())
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeMove) {
        println("Move message received")
        let messageMove = UnsafePointer<MessageMove>(data.bytes).memory
        self.delegate?.movePlayerAtIndex(self.indexForPlayerWithId(playerIDKey))
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameOver) {
        println("Game over message received")
        let messageGameOver = UnsafePointer<MessageGameOver>(data.bytes).memory
        self.delegate?.gameOver(messageGameOver.player1Won)
    }
}


//GameScene.swift


protocol GameKitHelperDelegate {
func matchEnded()
func matchStartedNow()
func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotePlayer playerID: GKPlayer!)

func moveForward()

}

func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotePlayer playerID: GKPlayer!) {



    if(_match != match) {

        println("works")
        return
    }
    _delegate?.match(match, didReceiveData: data, fromRemotePlayer: playerID)

    println("didnt work")
        }
```

Comment: Posting only the function that never gets called isn't very help. Please post the code that calls the function, as well as anything related.

Comment: @BlakeMerryman I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which iOS version are you using ?
Because it says clearly in documentation that following method:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromRemotePlayer:(GKPlayer *)player
```

is for iOS8 and above.

Whereas following method:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
```

is deprecated in iOS8.

Comment: Yeah use the other method that I mentioned.

Comment: is your func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotePlayer playerID: GKPlayer!) getting called in GameScene.swift ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84735/discussion-between-jaycee-and-coding22).